# Vertical space between \marginline notes

Tags: spacing, margins, koma-script

How can I increase the vertical space between margin notes following each other? In the default setting, the spacing between two notes is the same as their line spacing, which makes it visually impossible to distinguish the two notes.

MWE that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    Blabla \marginline{things that might span more than one line} and \marginline{other things} \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One can simply add a bit of `vspace` at the end of each note, e.g., like so:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\spacedmarginline}[1]{\marginline{{#1}\vspace{.7em}}}
\begin{document}
    Blabla \spacedmarginline{things that might span more than one line} and \spacedmarginline{other things} \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm of course happy to learn about problems with this approach and other, possibly better solutions!